# systemverilog function return value

Tags: system-verilog, verification

for the function below(btw, this function naming is bad),

Does the **ref_req** get changed when the function is closed ?

Since the argument is passed by value, and there is no return, my guess  is NO

But the code's owner tell me it's ok to code in this way, I'm getting confused

```
    virtual function ref_process(request_transaction ref_req);
        bit [255:0] data_tmp[];
        bit [31:0] strb_tmp[];
        int data_size;

        //ref_req.addr=ref_req.addr>>5;
        ref_req.addr=ref_req.addr;
        ref_req.len=ref_req.len/2;
        ref_req.size=5;
        data_size=ref_req.data.size/2+ref_req.data.size%2;
        `uvm_info("ref_process",$psprintf("ref_req len is %0d",ref_req.len),UVM_LOW)

        //strb process
        if(ref_req.trans_type==uvc_pkg::AXI_WRITE) begin
            strb_tmp=new[data_size];
            foreach(ref_req.strb[i]) begin
                if(i%2==0) begin
                    strb_tmp[i/2][15:0]=ref_req.strb[i];
                    //`uvm_info("write_initiated", $sformatf("strb_tmp[%d]: %0x, xact_strb[%0d]: %0x",i/2,strb_tmp[i/2],i,ref_req.strb[i]), UVM_LOW)
                end
                else begin
                    strb_tmp[i/2][31:16]=ref_req.strb[i];
                    //`uvm_info("write_initiated", $sformatf("strb_tmp[%d]: %0x, xact_strb[%0d]: %0x",i/2,strb_tmp[i/2],i,ref_req.strb[i]), UVM_LOW)
                end
            end
            ref_req.strb.delete();
            //ref_req.strb=new[ref_req.len];
            foreach(strb_tmp[i]) begin
                ref_req.strb.push_back(strb_tmp[i]);
            end

            //data process
            data_tmp=new[data_size];
            foreach(ref_req.data[i]) begin
                if(i%2==0) begin
                    data_tmp[i/2][127:0]=ref_req.data[i];
                    //`uvm_info("write_initiated", $sformatf("data_tmp[%d]: %0x, xact_data[%0d]: %0x",i/2,data_tmp[i/2],i,ref_req.data[i]), UVM_LOW)
                end
                else begin
                    data_tmp[i/2][255:128]=ref_req.data[i];
                    //`uvm_info("write_initiated", $sformatf("data_tmp[%d]: %0x, xact_data[%0d]: %0x",i/2,data_tmp[i/2],i,ref_req.data[i]), UVM_LOW)
                end
            end
            ref_req.data.delete();
            //ref_req.data=new[ref_req.len];
            foreach(data_tmp[i]) begin
                ref_req.data.push_back(data_tmp[i]);
            end
        end

    endfunction
```

Comment: it depends on the type of *request_transaction*. If it is a struct, you are correct, if this is a class object, the owner is correct. Class objects are  always represented (and as a result, passed in arguments) by references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is a piece of UVM code, `request_transaction` is most likely  a class *type* making `ref_req` a **input** class *variable* argument. When calling this function, a class *handle* to a class *object* gets copied into `ref_req`. If you were to change the function argument to a **ref** argument that would be a double reference and unnecessary.

Once you have a handle to a class *object*, you can write to class *members* of that object. That is exactly what this function does. A class variable always acts as a reference to a class object. See [my post](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/07/16/class-on-classes/) on class terminology.

BTW, this function has a 1-bit return value which is the implicit default in Verilog. It should really be declared with a `void` return type, meaning it has no return value.

Comment: thanks dave, Is this mechanism also works for C++ ?

Comment: C++ works he same way, but also allows passing classes by value. This invokes the copy constructor and is usually discouraged.